# How to access of a especific element in the response of Retrofit

Tags: java, android, arraylist, retrofit2

I'm querying an API with Retrofit, where the answer is this

```
[
{
    "Id": "BT00",
    "Text": "Registrarme"
},
{
    "Id": "BT01",
    "Text": "Iniciar sesión"
},
{
    "Id": "BT02",
    "Text": "Siguiente"
},
{
    "Id": "BT03",
    "Text": "Si"
},
{
    "Id": "BT04",
    "Text": "No"
}
]
```

and the body response look like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emHYP.png)

This call is stored in a ArrayList.

```
@SerializedName("Id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("Text")
@Expose
private String text;
//Getters&Setters
```

My answer is, how to access of elements of the response?

I tried the following ways but it does not work

```
apptext_id.setText(response.body().get(0).toString());
Logger.d("Body %s", response.body().get(0).toString());
Logger.d("Body %s", response.body().get(0));
```

the answer look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuAJK.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do to get the first element of the list is:  `response.body().get(0).getText();`

If you need to get **each** item, you need to:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {

    List<AppTextModel> list_elements = response.body();
    for (AppTextModel item : list_elements) {
        Logger.d("Body %s", item.getText()); // print every text item in list
    }
}
```

You also need in the POJO class:

```
public class AppTextModel {

    @SerializedName("Id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("Text")
    @Expose
    private String text;

    //Getters&Setters

    public String getText() {
        return text; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help ;)